# Identificar versão do JDK pelo Java

Tags: java, cmd, jdk

Estou criando uma IDE e quando o usuario aperta para rodar o código eu faço o seguinte:

```
try {
    File file = new File(arquivoSelecionado.nome);
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        fw.append(code.getText());  
        fw.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31\\bin\\javac "+file.getName());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java "+file.getName().replaceAll(".java", ""));   

} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

só que como é possivel ver eu estou colocando um caminho fixo para a pasta do jdk, neste caso a versão é a que se encontra no meu computador, o problema é que quando a versão do jdk é diferente da que esta no caminho fixo ele não executa o terminal rodando o programa

o que eu queria saber é se tem alguma forma de identificar a versão do jdk em que a IDE esta rodando

Comment: O ideal seria verificar a variável de ambiente do java e assim por ela saber o caminho de instalação do JDK

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java se existir a váriavel JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 3):

Talvez uma maneira mais eficiente seja inspecionar a variável de ambiente JAVA_HOME:

```
String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

A `String` que retorna desse método traz várias informações, entre elas, o caminho em que o compilador está instalado.

Apenas atente para o fato de que, se o computador a rodar seu programa não tiver o Java instalado, a variável `javaHome` estará nula.

Comment: Não é confiável, quiçá portável. Não creio que em sistemas *nix ao se instalar o Java se preencha essa variável de ambiente. Também tem o caso de que você pode ter múltiplos Javas instalados na máquina, mas a variável de ambiente é única; essa sua resposta não permite distinguir qual dos Javas instalados está de fato executando um programa

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Nada é 100% garantido. Se o computador destino da aplicação dele não tiver o Java instalado,  nenhuma solução proposta será satisfatória, seja variável de ambiente, seja vasculhando pastas de instalação etc. Quanto à variável de ambiente  ela também ocorre, e é preenchida, em ambientes *nix, como o meu, em que testei o código antes de criar a resposta.

Comment: O Java é ciente de si mesmo. Você pode requisitar que ele responda o que sabe sobre si mesmo, o que é diferente de pedir por uma variável de ambiente. E também aumenta-se a confiabilidade dessa solução